# Cythonのコンパイルができません。

Tags: python, cython

次のCythonのドキュメントを参考にしながら、簡単なCythonコードを作り(.pyx)、コンパイルを試みましたが、『:hello.c:(.text+0x1721): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'』というようなエラーが複数行出て.pydファイルができません。
ご教示をお願いいたします。

http://omake.accense.com/static/doc-ja/cython/src/quickstart/build.html

『python setup.py build_ext --inplace』を行うと、次のファイルは生成されます。
hello.c
build> temp.win-amd64-2.7> Release> hello.def
build> temp.win-amd64-2.7> Release> hello.o

次の記事の方法も見たのですが、上手くいきませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985109/how-to-compile-c-code-from-cython-with-gcc

環境は次の通りです。
windows 10 Pro/ 64bit
Python 2.7.14 ([MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)
Cython version 0.27.3
gcc 6.3.0
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a は存在しています。
環境変数(python系のパス)：
    PATH: c:\mingw\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
(PYTHONPATHは設定していません)

今回、Cythonのために追加でインストールしたものは、Cythonとgcc(MinGW)になります。
他に必要なモジュールなどありますでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

==========追記です==========
今回使用したコードは次の通りです。

```
[setup.py]
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

```
[hello.pyx]
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

上記二つのファイルを、同じフォルダ内に作り、cmdでそのディレクトリに移動し、『python setup.py build_ext --inplace』を行いました。
Cythonのドキュメント通りに作ったつもりですが、ご確認をお願いいたします。

(*上記追記内容を、回答欄に乗せてしまっていたのを、修正しました。ご迷惑をおかけいたしました。)

==========追記2==========
下記サイトを参考に、2つの方法を試してみました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707191/compiling-pyx-files

1. `gcc -shared -Wall -O3 -I Python27/include -L Python27/libs -o fib.so fib.c -l python27`を使う方法
   上記コマンドを一部修正し、`gcc -shared -Wall -O3 -I C:\Python27\include -L C:\Python27\libs -o hello.pyd hello.c -l C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a`のようにしてみたところ、`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`と表示されました(※C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.aは存在しているのですが。。)
   `gcc -shared -Wall -O3 -I C:\Python27\include -L C:\Python27\libs -o hello.pyd hello.c -l python27`だと、最初と同じエラーの`undefined reference to _imp__PyErr_SetString`が表示されます。
2. setup.pyを使う方法
   setup.pyをリンク先の回答のように書き直し、`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`をすると下記のエラーが出ました。(今まででてこなかったエラーです)

   running build_ext
   building 'hello' extension
   c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c hello.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.o
   In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\math.h:36:0,
                from C:\Python27\include/pyport.h:325,
                from C:\Python27\include/Python.h:58,
                from hello.cpp:17:
   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cmath:1157:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
   using ::hypot;
   　　　        ^~~~~
   error: command 'c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

   一応、"hello.cpp"はできていますが、buildフォルダの中は空っぽです。

以上、進捗のご報告となります。

Comment: @Haru「追記2」を書き加えました。ご確認をお願いいたします。
これまで表示されなかったエラーが出てきたので、それらについてこちらでも調査してみようと思います。

Comment: @Haru 管理者からバッチファイルを実行する形で行ってみましたが、同じようなエラーが出てしまいました。。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: @Haru
色んなコマンドを試してみたら、いつの間にか.pydができていました！！
しかし、どのコマンドをどういう環境で行うと良いのか、再現できるのかがちょっとわからないので、明日、情報を整理してご報告いたします。

Comment: stack overflowの運用について伺いたいのですが、上記のpydファイルを作る方法(再現できた手順/解決手順)を書き込む場合は、質問文に追記する方法で良いのでしょうか?
別回答を追加で、改めて書き込んだ方が良いのでしょうか?

Comment: そういう質問は、Metaでされるといいようです。スタックオーバーフロー自体の疑問については、Metaに行きましょう。画面右上のリンクから飛べます。

Comment: 連投になりますが、自己解決した場合は、自分で解答を書いて、解答を承認でもOKです。今までの経験から。ただし、自己承認は２日くらいの猶予が必要になります。また、自分に評価ポイントが入るわけではありませんが、未解決のまま放っておくのはなんとなく気持ち悪いので承認したほうがいいでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Haruさんからの紹介サイトなどを参考に、解決いたしましたのでご報告いたします。

1. 用意するスクリプト(.py, .pyx)は、初めに用意していたもので大丈夫でした。

   ```
   [setup.py]
   #! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   from distutils.core import setup
   from distutils.extension import Extension
   from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

   ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

   setup(
     name = 'Hello world app',
     cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
     ext_modules = ext_modules
   )
   ```

   ```
   [hello.pyx]
   def say_hello_to(name):
       print("Hello %s!" % name)
   ```

   下記2つの手順に沿って各種ソフトのインストールや設定を行った上で、上記二つのファイルを同じフォルダ内に作り、cmdでそのディレクトリに移動 & `python setup.py build_ext -i --compiler=msvc -DMS_WIN64`を行いました。
2. Cythonと[Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266/%22Microsoft%20Visual%20C%20%20%20Compiler%20for%20Python%202.7%22)をインストール
   恐らくですが、"Visual C++ Compiler"を使用する場合はgcc(MinGW)のインストールは必要ないかもしれません。(私のマシンには、色々試しているうちにgcc(MinGW)が入ってしまっている環境になってしまっておりましたが)
   [こちらのサイトも参考に](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/%22%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%AEURL%E3%82%82%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E3%81%AB%22)
3. productdirを設定する
   [こちらのサイト](http://www.geocities.jp/penguinitis2002/computer/programming/Python/cython/cython.html)の、`Python フォルダの "Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py" に設定を追記する`を参考に、
   `def find_vcvarsall(version):`関数の、
   `if not productdir or not os.path.isdir(productdir):`行の直前に、
   `productdir = "C:\\Users\\(ユーザー名)\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0"`を追記する。

私が解決した手順は以上です。
"Visual C++ Compiler"などのインストールなどは問題なくできていたようですが、手順3の"productdir"が設定しない限り、エラー(ツールが見つからない)で止まってしまうようです。

この度は、解決にご協力頂いた @Haru さんをはじめとする多くの皆様にお礼申し上げます。
ありがとうございました。